# requirejs conflict when loading twice in the same page

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm loading requirejs into a page like this:

`<script src="components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script>`

Then I have another requirejs code inside a function on an external script that I'm loading into the same page (because it's a widget that uses requirejs). The problem is that the second require is taking the config from the first one. It looks to me that there is a conflict on the global scope, which I do not understand since the requirejs code is encapsulated into a function.

Any toughts?

What is the best way to load requirejs twice into the same page wihtout messing things up?

Comment: Iknow this is old, but do you remember the error? Not sure if require is being loaded twice.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had a similar problem about a year ago, [which I managed to resolve myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279196/context-and-nested-modules-in-requirejs).

What you need is requireJS's [contexts](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion).  On the page where you have require running, pop open your dev tools and type the following:

```
require.s.contexts
```

What you should see is an object with one property, `_`: this is the default context.  What you need is to run two entirely separate instances of require, or two contexts.  A small bit of sample code, which you can replace your current config setup with:

```
var requireContextOne = require.config({
    context: 'contextOne',
    baseUrl: 'whatever',
    /* THE REST OF YOUR FIRST CONFIG */
});

var requireContextTwo = require.config({
    context: 'contextTwo',
    baseUrl: 'whatever',
    /* THE REST OF YOUR SECOND CONFIG */
});

//Start both your contexts
(function(){
    //Remember to pass "require" as the first variable, otherwise you'll get all sorts of errors!
    requireContextOne(['require', 'topModule'], function(require, topModule){
        topModule.initialize();
    });

    //Your second context - even if you load the same module, it will be a separate "instance" from the one used in the first context
    requireContextTwo(['require', 'topModule'], function(require, topModule, anotherModule){
        topModule.initialize( anotherModule.start() );
    });
})();
```

Now if you run `require.s.contexts` in the console, you'll see you have two contexts: 'contextOne' and 'contextTwo'.  Moreover, if you type something like `require.s.contexts.contextOne.defined`, you can take a peek at all of the modules that that particular context has loaded.

**Edited with a longshot proposed response to @jplozano's comment**

```
//Your widget's main file
define(function() {
    var widgetRequireContext = require.config({
        context: 'myWidget',
        baseUrl: 'whatever',
        /* THE REST OF YOUR WIDGET CONFIG */
    });

    //Note that I use "requirejs", not "require," to ensure we keep the reference to global variable
    widgetRequireContext(['require', 'submodule/a', 'submodule/b'], function(requirejs, subA, subB){
        /* THE REST OF YOUR MAIN MODULE CODE IS WRAPPED IN HERE */
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try it out. One thing I forgot to mention is that I have absolutely no control over the main requirejs. I only have control over the widget's requirejs because is the one I'm developing.

Comment: Then you're in rough shape.  Can you describe the scenario a little bit more?  My hunch is that  you could make a context within whatever the "main" module of your widget (the one that gets loaded first).  I do edited my answer - no idea if it will work, but give it a shot.

Comment: Good god the grammar in that comment was awful.  I apologize to the English language...

Comment: Don't worry. I've tried your proposal but didn't work either. I end up loading dependencies with $.getScript cause I cannot waste any more time on this. Still frustrated by the way RequireJS works on the global scope.

Comment: Try browserify if it makes sense for your project.  It should be able to export a compiled file with a single IIFE with a factory wrapper, which could then be loaded by requireJS, commonJS, node, etc

Answer (score 0):

Don't load Require.js twice. If you have a library that internally has AMD modules, then it can come with an embedded copy of Almond.js instead. Almond is designed for this usage, it is by the same author as Require.js.

This will allow you to have modules at the global level (loaded by Require.js), and those modules themselves can internally be composed of inner / private modules.